# Golang: Parsing all templates which are in different directories?

Tags: file, parsing, go, directory

This is my directory structure:

```
[root@abc]# ll
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  133 Mar 26 16:13 credit
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  132 Mar 26 16:17 form
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6003 Mar 27 19:30 main.go
```

`var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("form/*"))` parses all files inside **form** directory. How to parse **credit** directory files also ?

```
var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("form/*","credit/*"))
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("*/*"))`

quick example:

directory structure:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  194 Mar 28 07:39 main.go
drwxr-xr-x  3 User  staff  102 Mar 28 07:38 test1
drwxr-xr-x  3 User  staff  102 Mar 28 07:38 test2
```

contents of test1

```
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  0 Mar 28 07:38 template1.html
```

contents of test2

```
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  0 Mar 28 07:38 template2.html
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("*/*"))
    fmt.Println(tmpl.DefinedTemplates())
}
```

Output:

```
; defined templates are: "template2.html", "template1.html"
```

template.ParseGlob uses filepath.Glob to do the globbing.

```
// parseGlob is the implementation of the function and method ParseGlob. (Lines 461-474 of template.go)
func parseGlob(t *Template, pattern string) (*Template, error) {
    if err := t.checkCanParse(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    filenames, err := filepath.Glob(pattern) // <- right here
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(filenames) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("html/template: pattern matches no files: %#q", pattern)
    }
    return parseFiles(t, filenames...)
}
```

So it follows those same rules:

```
// Glob returns the names of all files matching pattern or nil
// if there is no matching file. The syntax of patterns is the same
// as in Match. The pattern may describe hierarchical names such as
// /usr/*/bin/ed (assuming the Separator is '/').
//
// Glob ignores file system errors such as I/O errors reading directories.
// The only possible returned error is ErrBadPattern, when pattern
// is malformed. (Lines 226-233 path/filepath/match.go)
```

The discription of Match is:

```
// Match reports whether name matches the shell file name pattern.
// The pattern syntax is:
//
//  pattern:
//      { term }
//  term:
//      '*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
//      '?'         matches any single non-Separator character
//      '[' [ '^' ] { character-range } ']'
//                  character class (must be non-empty)
//      c           matches character c (c != '*', '?', '\\', '[')
//      '\\' c      matches character c
//
//  character-range:
//      c           matches character c (c != '\\', '-', ']')
//      '\\' c      matches character c
//      lo '-' hi   matches character c for lo <= c <= hi
//
// Match requires pattern to match all of name, not just a substring.
// The only possible returned error is ErrBadPattern, when pattern
// is malformed.
//
// On Windows, escaping is disabled. Instead, '\\' is treated as
// path separator.
//
```